# authenticating pentaho server in spring application

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer

I have a spring application with users having roles and based on roles the user is authenticated to particular functions. if I integrate Pentaho server in this application how can avoid the re-authenticating Pentaho server.?

Answer (score 0):

There is something called single sign-on,Through which you can by pass login and the same credentials for your application will be used in Pentaho Server as well.
Process is quit a long,i will suggest to do some research and you will get you answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, I don't want to go to single sign-on or LDAP authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho uses Spring as well. I would suggest you to play with `applicationContext-spring-security.xml` located under `pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system`. You might be able to obtain login information from session of your Spring app and then use it to authenticate to Pentaho.

I have never done it. It is just an idea that might help you.

Comment: So, I am getting user details from my application session in my spring boot app. but how to trigger the Pentaho with a REST call from my application so that it will authenticate the Pentaho.
I thought of sending a post call once the user clicks the submit button on the login page. there I will send a post call to Pentaho with user details. but I am not able to figure out how that post call will look like which authenticated the pentaho.